# Best Mercurial mode for Emacs?

Tags: version-control, emacs, mercurial

The [Emacs Wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MercurialMode) lists several modes for supporting mercurial inside of Emacs, including the built-in VC mode.  Is it worth exploring any of the other modes, such as the one distributed with mercurial itself?

Comment: Perhaps [this link](http://xtalk.msk.su/~ott/en/writings/emacs-vcs/EmacsMercurial.html) might be of help...

Comment: See http://ananthakumaran.in/monky/index.html (HG analog of magit).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest [DVC](http://xtalk.msk.su/~ott/en/writings/emacs-vcs/EmacsDVC.html).  It supports other distributed version control systems (notably git), it's easy to configure and it works as much like the default VC mode as reasonable.  It also seems to have a larger user-base than the mercurial mode.

Comment: I tried DVC, but found that it required me to jump through too many hoops just to commit my changes. I guess it might make sense if you subscribe to DVC's workflow, but for me, it sucked all the fun out of both Emacs and Mercurial.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on which other DVCS you using.  If you using several, then DVC could be good choice.

If you want to get native support of mercurial, then you can use either mercurial.el (described in my article), either [aHg](https://es.fbk.eu/people/griggio/ahg.html) package, that has some advantages over mercurial.el.  I plan to update my article with description of this package, but i don't know when it will be done :-(